# Lua replacement for the % operator

Tags: math, lua, modulo

I want to check, if a number is divisible by another number:

```
for i = 1, 100 do
    if i % 2 == 0 then
        print( i .. " is divisible.")
    end
end
```

This should work without any problems, but with the Lua in my server the script doesn't run if there is a `%` in the script... I dont know whats the reason, so is there any "replacement" for that? So I could check the number divsibility?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Lua is the server running?

Comment: I think its 5.0 or later `:S`.

Comment: sounds like you have some encoding problems; maybe if you find what encoding is it, you might be able to sneak a `%` through.  try '%%' or '\%' or '%25'

Comment: I am downvoting this question because I believe it is asking the wrong question: The real question here is "Why is `%` not working for me in Lua"? According to the [Lua Documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html) *Lua supports the usual arithmetic operators: the binary + (addition), - (subtraction), * (multiplication), / (division), % (modulo), and ^ (exponentiation); and unary - (negation).*

Comment: @Javier Lua 5.0 did not support the `%` operator. 5.1 and later however, does. See my answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's not ideal, but according to the [Lua 5.2 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.1):

> a % b == a - math.floor(a/b)*b

Comment: This seems a workaround for older versions of Lua. At least % works fine in Lua 5.2 and later.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson `%` was added as an operator in Lua 5.1.

Answer (score 58):

Use `math.fmod(x,y)` which does what you want:

> Returns the remainder of the division of x by y that rounds the
>   quotient towards zero.

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-math.fmod

Comment: `math.fmod` did not exist in Lua 5.0, it was renamed from `math.mod` to `math.fmod` in Lua 5.1. However, Lua 5.1 also added the `%` operator, so if the OP is running Lua 5.0, `fmod` is the wrong function to use.

Answer (score 8):

Lua 5.0 did not support the `%` operator.

> Lua supports the usual arithmetic operators: the binary + (addition), - (subtraction), * (multiplication), / (division), and ^ (exponentiation); and unary - (negation).
>
> https://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html

Lua 5.1 however, does support the `%` operator.

> Lua supports the usual arithmetic operators: the binary + (addition), - (subtraction), * (multiplication), / (division), % (modulo), and ^ (exponentiation); and unary - (negation).
>
> https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html

If possible, I would recommend that you upgrade. If that is not possible, use `math.mod` which is listed as one of the [Mathematical Functions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html#5.5) in 5.0 (It was renamed to `math.fmod` in [Lua 5.1](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.6))

Answer (score 6):

```
function mod(a, b)
    return a - (math.floor(a/b)*b)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for i = 1, 100 do
    if (math.mod(i,2) == 0) then
        print( i .. " is divisible.")
    end
end
```

Comment: Strange that it's undocumented in recent documentation. (At least with a simple test, it seems to work like fmod.)

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson It's not undocumented in recent documentation, the function was called `mod` in 5.0 and renamed to `fmod` in 5.1.

Answer (score 3):

Use `math.fmod`, accroding [lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7.2) `math.mod` was renamed to `math.fmod` in lua 5.1.