# Some operators are not allowed by Lua

Tags: c++, c++11, lua, symbols

I'm having a really odd issue with a Lua implementation into my C++ project. For some reason, it doesn't allow scripts containing operators like `#`, `:`, `%` (and some more, less important) to be executed.

In the results...

I need to use `for i = 1, table.getn(tbl) do` instead of `for i = 1, #tbl do`.

I need to use `string.gsub(str, [..])` instead of `str:gsub([..])`.

and so on... This is getting really annoying looking for a work-arounds.

My first thought was the encoding. I have tried with multiple common encodings though and none worked.

Errors I am having:

When using `str:gsub([..])` instead of `string.gsub(str, [..])`:

```
attempt to index global `str' (a string value)
```

When using `#tbl` instead of `table.getn(tbl)`:

```
unexpected symbol near `#'
```

***What might be the problem?*** I will appreciate every solution because I am out of ideas.

---

**Specifications**:

Lua version:

```
#define LUA_VERSION "Lua 5.0.3"
```

C++ 11,
FreeBSD 10

Comment: What about `%` isn't working?

Comment: @EtanReisner It simply doesn't work at all. Eg. when doing `a % 2 == 0` I need to work around this (this guy here had similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695697/lua-replacement-for-the-operator). 

Btw. updated my question and added errors I'm getting back.

Comment: The `%` *operator* is a relatively recent addition to Lua, added in 5.1.

Comment: So there I have my issue. It seems I need to simply update the Lua to have everything working.

Comment: Or you can write code that doesn't depend on the newer features. BTW, it's not the *characters* that are the issue it's the operators. (All those characters are supported in comments and string literals, for example.) You might want to update your question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The length operator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5) is a lua 5.1 addition. It did not exist in lua 5.0.

Similarly the default string metatable appears to be a lua 5.1 addition.

Compare the lua 5.0 implementation of [`luaopen_string`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.0/lstrlib.c.html#luaopen_string) to the lua 5.1 implementation of [`luaopen_string`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lstrlib.c.html#luaopen_string).

Similarly (again) the modulo operation is also a 5.1 addition. Compare the `Arithmetic Operators` section of the [`5.0 manual`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html#2.5.1) and the [`5.1 manual1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.1).

The 5.1 manual section includes what the operator is defined as so you can implement it yourself (or use whatever other definition you need instead).

Comment: Thanks for this. I will update my Lua version then :-)