# count++ and count%x translation from Java to Lua

Tags: java, lua, coronasdk

I'm building a program in Lua.

In my code, I have to translate `count++` from Java to Lua. How would I go about this?
I assume it's `count = count + 1`, but is there another way to go about this method?

Also, when you write `(count % 20 == 0)`, is the right translation in Lua, `(math.mod(count,20) == 0)`?

I have tried both the above lines, but one of the two seem to be not working.

Comment: I have tried count = count + 1 in the (math.mod(count,20)==0) method. I tried debugging it and it seems that it's not working correctly. I am not sure which of the two is wrong. :/

Comment: Ask one question per time. The two questions are not related.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua replacement for the % operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695697/lua-replacement-for-the-operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a % b == a - math.floor(a/b)*b

from: [Lua replacement for the % operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695697/lua-replacement-for-the-operator)

And count = count + 1 is fine

You can see this in action by pasting

```
count = 1 
count = count + 1
print(count)
print((count - math.floor(count/2)*2) == 0) --ie count % 2 == 0
```

into http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

Comment: For integers `a % b` does the same thing in Java as it does in Lua, so there is no need to translate.